# UIAlertView performSelectorInBackground

Tags: iphone, background, uialertview, nsthread

on iOS5 I can use method to show `UIAlertView`:

```
[alert performSelectorInBackground: @ selector (show) withObject: nil];
```

on iOS6 crash my app, why?

That the replacing?

Thanks

Comment: Any particular error message, crash log?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you performing that selector in the background? Showing an alert view probably isn't something you want to be doing on a background thread.

Comment: performSelector in background runs that selector on a background thread so that it doesn't stop other tasks from performing on the main thread. I don't think it's really what you're looking for here. Just change it to [alert show]

Answer (score 0):

You aren't suppose to do UI stuff in the background. It will make your app crash. You normally do stuff like loading data from a server in the background or computational expensive operation, but never do anything that's in the UIKit framework in a background thread.

Comment: on iOS5 don't have this problem, why?